# How to update this sql query?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, sql-update, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to update the mysql table. But I am getting the error. Can you tell where is my query is going wrong?

Code:

```
UPDATE unlisted 
SET unlisted.cin_no = karnataka_cin.cin_no
WHERE unlisted.company_name = karnataka_cin.company_name;
```

Error:

## 1054 - Unknown column 'karnataka_cin.company_name' in 'where clause'

Comment: You have to join the other table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of an UPDATE:

```
UPDATE unlisted u
  JOIN karnataka_cin k
    ON u.company_name = k.company_name
   SET u.cin_no = k.cin_no
```

Answer (score 0):

Join **karnataka_cin** table in your query.

See here for further details on joining- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com